# Folder created and modified dates issue

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using SharePoint online.
In one library we have few folders, for 3 folder created date and modified date are showing incorrect.
For example folder created date is December 2022 and modified date November 2022.
May I know why it is showing
[image]

Comment: Screenshot with those dates would be very much appreciated to understand your question, as SharePoint Online to show dates like that, is not idle behavior.

Comment: Hello Pradip, Added screenshot

Comment: Is there any sort of column formatting applied to any of the columns there. Cause it seems every item has same `Created` date value. Also please verify if they are calculated column with same name as reserved name with different internal name.

Comment: Actually I migrated data from network drive to SharePoint. 10 months back